# How can I send a GWT-RPC request with HttpClient?

Tags: java, gwt, httprequest, apache-commons-httpclient

I am using the Apache HTTPClient API to send HTTPRequests, and so far it's worked with standard requests. Now I want to send a GWT-RPC request and show the response, but I always receive the following error from the GWT-RPC server:

```
 //EX[2,1,"com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.IncompatibleRemoteServiceException/3936916533","This application is out of date, please click the refresh button on your browser. ( Malformed or old RPC message received - expecting version 5 )"],0,5]
```

Actually, I have to send the following data with the request:

```
5|0|5|http://172.16.103.244:38081/kunagi/scrum.ScrumGwtApplication/|6E611C647A0C98D5A31A2506E16D81D6|scrum.client.ScrumService|startConversation|I|1|2|3|4|1|5|-1|
```

but I don't know how.

When I retrieve the request code from FireBug, I find the above data as a source in the post area.

Comment: IIRC, GWTTestCase uses HTTPClient to make RPC calls.  You could look at it's implementation and find out.

Comment: If you want to have an easier time developing your app you should consider sending a textual representation of your data (ie: JSON or XML).

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [gwt-syncproxy](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-syncproxy/) project. It does exactly what you are looking for, faking RCP calls from Java code. If you don't want to rely your project on [gwt-syncproxy](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-syncproxy/), you could look at it's implementation and find out how the create valid requests.